# Magic Mouse: Turn it into a touchpad

Tags: magic-mouse

Does anyone know of a program or utility that will turn my Magic Mouse into a touchpad (I'm running OS 10.5.8)?  That is, with the nice multi-touch surface, why not just use all of the MacBook gestures (most importantly moving the pointer and tap-to-click/tap-to-click-drag) and ditch the need to actually move the mouse around?  This way you could use the mouse just holding it in your hand.

Comment: One use case is when you either have a non-trackable surface (e.g. glass) or if you don't have a surface at all (you're standing up).

Answer (score 5):

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.macstories.net/reviews/bettertouchtool-brings-gestures-to-your-mac-apps/) adds many new, fully customizable gestures to Magic Mouse and Macbook Touchpad

Comment: I had looked at that but it doesn't appear to add the straight-up touch mousing (moving the cursor around the screen without moving the mouse).  Also, I need it on 10.5.8--will update original question with OS requirement.

Comment: As of 1/9/2010 BetterTouchTool added this feature, Touchpad Mode, available in the latest build from here: http://blog.boastr.net/?p=1277. Alas, you still need OS 10.6.

Answer (score 4):

This is answer is a bit late, but in case you never found it:

[Mouse Wizard](https://samuco.net/mousewizard.html) works wonderfully well and has a mode that does exactly what you're looking for. You turn the mouse sideways and use it as a normal trackpad. I actually combine that with another program, so that I can use it as a trackpad *and* retain two-finger-scroll capabilities.

Comment: Nice job. Not sure if the OP will ever except your answer though.

Comment: Dead link and author hasn't returned in 5 yrs.

Comment: The software still exists. I fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you wanted, but you could try Jitouch. I think it is a fantastic app. Adds tons of extra gestures to your magic trackpad and mouse. I'm not sure if it allows you to use your finger to move the pointer though.

http://www.jitouch.com/index.php?page=magicmouse